# Combine lines when writing to file in Python?

Tags: python

So I'm trying to write all this info to a .txt file, but due to the names being pulled from a .txt file that goes

Liam

Noah

William

etc...

When I write to a file, it puts the first and last names on separate lines from everything else.

I've looked on StackOverflow for a solution but I couldn't find anything specific enough.

```
password = input('Enter the Password you would like to use ')

open('names.txt', 'r+')
lines = open("names.txt").readlines() 
firstName = lines[0] 
words = firstName.split() 
firstNameChoice = random.choice(lines)

open('names.txt', 'r+')
lines = open("names.txt").readlines() 
lastName = lines[0] 
words = lastName.split() 
lastNameChoice = random.choice(lines)



def signUp():
    randomNumber = str(random.randint(0,10000))

    accountFile = open('accounts.txt', 'a')
    accountFile.write(firstNameChoice)
    accountFile.write(lastNameChoice)
    accountFile.write(randomNumber)
    accountFile.write('@')
    accountFile.write(catchall)
    accountFile.write(':')
    accountFile.write(password)
    accountFile.write('\n')

signUp()

Expectation would be everything printed to one line but that's not the case.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If my understanding is right then you want to write everything in one line.

The variables you are writing containing `\n` while writing into the file.

So you have to replace it with a `' '`. Replace this code into your program like:

```
 accountFile.write(firstNameChoice.replace('\n',' '))
 accountFile.write(lastNameChoice.replace('\n',' '))
 accountFile.write(str(randomNumber).replace('\n',' '))
 accountFile.write('@'.replace('\n',' '))
#accountFile.write(catchall)
 accountFile.write(':'.replace('\n',' '))
 accountFile.write(str(password).replace('\n',' '))
```

Now it will print like this `WilliamWilliam448@:dsada`

By the way I dont know what you mean by `catchall`

Comment: Thanks! I had to modify the code a bit to get what I wanted though. What I did was turn ' ' into '' and got rid of the replace \n with no replacement for firstNameChoice. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

As a quick fix for your problem, you could merge all writing commands in one line:

```
with open('accounts.txt', 'a') as accountFile: # using a context manager is highly recommended
    # with spaces
    accountFile.write('{} {} {} @ {} : {} \n'.format(
                                                    firstNameChoice, 
                                                    lastNameChoice, 
                                                    randomNumber, 
                                                    catchall, 
                                                    password
                                                    )
                  )    

     # without spaces
     accountFile.write('{}{}{}@{}:{}\n'.format(
                                                    firstNameChoice, 
                                                    lastNameChoice, 
                                                    randomNumber, 
                                                    catchall, 
                                                    password
                                                    )
                  )
```

Comment: This gives me the following:
Exception has occurred: IndexError
tuple index out of range

Comment: This just spaces out the output like so:
Amirah
\n
Bria
 \n
3621 @ a : a

Comment: if you don't want spaces, use the second accountFile.write in the edited post

Answer (score 0):

The reason it puts it all on a new line is because the strings of your names contains the "\n" on the end because it has an enter to a new line. There is an easy fix for this.

Where you define your first and last name variables add `.rstrip()` at the end. Like this:

`firstNameChoice = random.choice(lines).rstrip()`

`lastNameChoice = random.choice(lines).rstrip()`

Answer (score 0):

```
def signUp():
    randomNumber = str(random.randint(0,10000))
    accountFile = open('accounts.txt', 'a')
    accountFile.write(f'{firstNameChoice} {lastNameChoice} {randomNumber} @ {catchall}: {password} \n')
```

Comment: Please explain why this code is an answer to the question.

Comment: it collects information into one line. If it's wrong, please explain